# Why does NHibernate Session.Save locks the database?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, dotnetopenauth

I've built a small ASP.NET MVC web app with NHibernate as ORM. On every HTTP request beginning I create a session and open a transaction and close it at the end of the request.

```
// Begin request

session = StaticSessionManager.OpenSession();    
session.BeginTransaction();

// End of request

currentSession.Transaction.Commit();
currentSession.Flush();
currentSession.Close();
```

Now I'm also using [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) API for Facebook/Google Login. In order for me to register a new user the API expects me to update a Table(say UserProfile) with some user information. This I'm doing via Nhibernate's Save()

```
session.Save(new UserProfile { UserName = userName });
```

In the same web request the DotNetOpenAuth API expects to read the above inserted data from that table(UserProfile).

Now this is leading to a deadlock scenario as NHibernate's Save applied some sort of lock on the database. Even when I manually try to read data off that table using SQL server Management studio, it seems to wait until the web request times out.

Now I've tried explicit flushing after Save

```
session.Flush();
```

but even this doesn't get rid of the lock. I want my DotNetOpenAUth API to be able to read the most updated data.

Currently I'm comiting the Transaction after Save and re-opening one more after. I'm not sure if this is the best practice/has any drawbacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### When to call Flush?

With default settings (`FlushMode` on `ISession`), calling `Commit()` on the NHibernate transaction will automatically flush changes. In some situations we want to flush manually, but calling `Flush()` after transaction commit is bad for a number of reasons:

- Since the commit itself has already flushed, we know there are no more changes to flush, so it's useless. NHibernate, however, doesn't know it's useless, so it will still dirty check all loaded objects. That is, superflouos flushing is bad for performance.
- If there is indeed some dirty state to send to the database, such an update will be performed outside the transaction, which is ususally not what we want.

### Database locking

Typically, when the database acquires a lock of some sort, that lock remains until the transaction is committed or roll backed. Flushing does not terminate a transaction and therefore has no releasing effect on locks.

### Attempted solution

From your description it would appear that you are using one database connection (through the NHibernate session) to create the UserProfile, and another database connection (in the same web request) to read it back. This later connection blocks because the transaction on the first connection isn't finished yet. (Clearly it must lock, since the database doesn't yet know if the transaction will be successful or not.)

Try to find a way to do any of the following:

- When you create the user profile, do so on a separate transaction (and possibly session) that you can commit before returning.
- Or make the "reading back" of the user profile use the same database connection, so that it can be done within the same transaction. I'm not familiar with the DotNetOpenAuth API, but see if there is way to override the read operation so you can do it through NHibernate, or alternatively try to inject the session.Connection into DotNetOpenAuth.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I've read that the default setting of Nhibernate is FlushMode.Auto, which is flush on the next dirty read. Going by that logic i believe even if you do commit your Transaction, it may not be flushed into the Database, unless you either close the session or read some data after commit. 
Further off the two solutions proposed, the second is not an option. DotNetOpenAuth doesn't use Nhibernate. 
I tried creating a nested Transaction, but apparently Nhibernate cannot have nested transactions, so that didn't work. But can a SessionFactory have concurent multiple session?

Comment: @noobMama FlushMode.Auto means to flush when NHibernate thinks it's necessary, which includes transaction commit and when dirty state may affect the outcome of a query (http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing). And even if you do must flush manually, it should normally be _before_ commit. On the other hand, closing the session does not force a flush.

Comment: @noobMama Like I said, I'm not familiar with DotNetOpenAuth, but the text in you question led me to believe that you were using some extension point to call your "save new user profile" snippet. It seemed logical that there would a similar extension point for reads, where you could hook up something based on NHibernate. I do find it difficult to believe that DotNetOpenAuth would not have extension points to plug in you own database access. But also, session.Connection is also available if you can only plug in a basic ADO.Net connection.

Comment: @noobMama Of course a sessionFactory can have multiple concurrent sessions. Otherwise you couldn't handle multiple concurrent web requests with the very common session-per-request pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying that, I'll dig into the plugging in session.Connection bit later. But for now If i were to choose between creating a new session and a new transaction in it vs  Closing the existing transaction and creating a new one in the same session(created on start of HTTP request). Which would you suggest and why ?

Comment: @noobMama The difference is whether you want to keep tracking already loaded objects in the session. If yes, then you have to reuse the session. If not you can either replace the session or just call `Clear()` on the existing one.